# How to "Pull Down" LVDS input in FPGA

Tags: fpga, pullup, pulldown, lvds, microsemi-fpga

One of my hardware modules uses a state machine which is triggered when the input signal *IN* is HI (that's an LVDS pair on Microsemi proASIC FPGA). The problem arises when nothing is connected to the LVDS input pair - so my state machine triggers spontaneously, as expected. I wanted to "Pull down" the input and tried to set the constraints for *IN_P* and *IN_N* pads with *-res_pull down* and *-res_pull up* respectively in the constraints file as suggested [here](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Virtex-Family-FPGAs/LVDS-inputs-floating-state/td-p/511653). This gave me errors saying that those are unknown pin attributes. And indeed, when I opened the interactive compile interface, there was no option to select up/down pin pulling for the LVDS standard.

[image]

But then, how to set my LVDS input to a known (low) state when it is not connected? Is this limitation Microsemi specific, device specific, or there is no such thing as pulling LVDS pairs internally?

Comment: What device? I've had to use external pull up/downs with microsemi devices before.

Comment: @DonFusili It's a M1A3P1000L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Under the set_io command](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/131597-design-constraints-guide) (page 282, specifically), it lists that only certain IO standards can take pullups/pulldowns. [Newer versions of this guide](https://www.microsemi.com/document-portal/doc_view/136314-design-constraints-for-libero-soc-v11-5-user-guide) list what standards can take pullups/pulldowns, but aren't for the ProASIC3 specifically. Unfortunately, LVDS isn't one of the standards that can take pullups/pulldowns.

Comment: So, need to use external resistors?

Comment: It appears that way, unfortunately.